# Applescript: Signature syntax is broken after update to OS X Sierra

Tags: macos, email, applescript, signature, macos-sierra

Since upgrading to Mac OS X Sierra, the following AppleScript does not work for adding a signature to an e-mail in Apple Mail.

I haven't yet found a workaround, so thought I might quiz the group.

**No longer working:**

```
set message signature of msg to signature theSignatureName
```

Comment: A number of users are reporting issues with AppleScripts since then.  It is best to file a [Bug Report](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login.html?appIdKey=77e2a60d4bdfa6b7311c854a56505800be3c24e3a27a670098ff61b69fc5214b&sslEnabled=true&rv=3)

Comment: Perhaps it's FINALLY showing its age. * joking *

Comment: Oh yeah.  AppleScript and Mail have been a challenging combo for at least 2 decades now.  Keeps us scripters on our toes devising workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I submitted a bug report along with lots of info that Apple requested. After about a week or so, here's the response I received.

> Engineering has determined that your bug report (28851572) is a duplicate of another issue (28497651) and will be closed.

I'll continue to track this as much as possible, but for now... the ball is in Apple's court.